# If statements not working correctly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, if-statement

I'm making a space invaders game in vb.net however for my high score system it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Whenever I try to get a lower score than my current high score, the input box for when I actually do get a higher score than my current high score still pops up

`Best` design name is the label responsible for showing who has the best high score

```
If Val(Lives.Text) = 0 Then`your text`

            MsgBox("You Lose!")



            If Val(score.Text) > Val(Highscore.Text) Then

                Highscore.Text = score.Text
                Highscore.Text = "high Score: " & Highscore.Text

                Best.Text = InputBox("Enter your name")

                Best.Text = "best Player: " & Best.Text

                filenum = FreeFile()
                FileOpen(filenum, "score.txt", OpenMode.Output)
                PrintLine(filenum, Best.Text)
                PrintLine(filenum, Highscore.Text)
                FileClose(filenum)

                Close()

            Else
                Close()

            End If

        End If
```

I tried switching around the `if` statements but nothing happened

Comment: You need to actually debug your code, by setting a breakpoint and stepping through it line by line, examining the state at every step. If you do that then you'll probably be able to fix the issue yourself. If you can't, you can tell us exactly where and how the actual behaviour doesn't match your expectations. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn first. You need to determine exactly what you expect to happen before each step and then see whether that did happen after each step. Use the Autos, Locals, watch and Immediate windows to evaluate variables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your score values separatet from text.
if you say Val(Highscore.text) you will get zero if the Highscore.text is "High score: 12345"

Answer (score 0):

```
If Val(Lives.Text) = 0 Then
    MsgBox("You Lose!")

    If Val(score.Text) > Val(Highscore.Text) Then
        Highscore.Text = score.Text
        Highscore.Text = "high Score: " & Highscore.Text

        Best.Text = InputBox("Enter your name")
        Best.Text = "best Player: " & Best.Text

        filenum = FreeFile()
        FileOpen(filenum, "score.txt", OpenMode.Output)
        PrintLine(filenum, Best.Text)
        PrintLine(filenum, Highscore.Text)
        FileClose(filenum)
    End If

    Close()
End If
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).